# Facebook login is not working on website

Tags: django, facebook, python-social-auth

can someone please help me. I am getting the following error when trying to login with Facebook:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

My redirect URI is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/complete/facebook

Comment: And did you specify it in the app settings …?

Comment: Yes, I specified in the app settings.

Comment: Do you get this when you call the login dialog, or afterwards in the next step, when your app makes the API call to exchange the code for a token?

Comment: This only tells me that the app is still in dev mode … And how can you not be sure, either you get this shown while you are on facebook.com, when the login dialog is shown … or it shows afterwards, on your site.

Comment: @CBroe can you please suggest me what's wrong I tried various redirect URIs and none of them seems to work.

Comment: Check what the browser address bar contains in that moment. The _exact_ value the `redirect_uri` parameter has there, needs to be in your settings.

Comment: That looks ok. Do you have the other, general app settings filled out correctly as well? App Domains, Website platform settings, …

Comment: Double-check that you are using the correct app id. If that’s not it, then show screenshots of your settings.

Comment: Not ignoring half of what error messages are saying is the key, you know … _“Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on”_

Comment: You rock!. I am sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: Well yeah sometimes we all need someone else to point out the obvious ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your URI from this:
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/complete/facebook
to this:
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/auth/complete/facebook

- you can add for each tranlation you may add. (en, fr, etc)

Hope it helps.